# Categorizing variables based on conditions stored in another table SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to categorize variables from one table which looks like this:

```
Var1 Var2
19   0.2
30   0.1
45   0.2
```

With table that stores conditions for the categroziation

```
variable condition   category
Var1     Var1<20         1
Var1     40>Var1>=20     2
Var1     Var1>=40        3
Var2     Var2<0.2        1
Var2     Var2>=0.2       2
```

And the result of that would be a new table created containing categories of variables based on first table:

```
Var1 Var2
1     2
2     1
3     2
```

Comment: Does it need to be a table? Because this would be easy with `proc format`

Comment: the table contains the conditions as there are around 600 of them in my dataset

Comment: Are all your conditions valid SAS expressions?

Comment: yes they are valid

Comment: So actually the thing im looking for is how to create macro that would retrieve them from the table and creade conditions for each of it and apply it to the values in the first table

Comment: Have you explored the `call execute` Data step function?

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of this other thread?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665307/categorize-variables-basing-on-conditions-from-other-data-set/36670188?noredirect=1#comment84161806_36670188

Comment: that thread did not have solution to the problem which now is solved

Comment: You just need to do code generation, and that is probably easier to do with a data step than macro language.  But you could create a macro if you wanted to vary the name of the input dataset and input metadata file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a duplicate of this previous question. [Categorize variables basing on conditions from other data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665307/categorize-variables-basing-on-conditions-from-other-data-set/36670188?noredirect=1#comment84161806_36670188)

Code generation from data is much easier to create and debug if you just use SAs code to do it and not add in complications of macro code.

Here is the answer again in more detail.  First let's make your example data printouts into actual SAS datasets.

```
data rawdata ;
  input Var1 Var2;
cards;
19   0.2
30   0.1
45   0.2
;

data metadata ;
  input variable :$32. condition :$200. category ;
cards;
Var1     Var1<20         1
Var1     40>Var1>=20     2
Var1     Var1>=40        3
Var2     Var2<0.2        1
Var2     Var2>=0.2       2
;
```

Now let's generate an SQL select statement with a CASE statement to generate each output variable from the metadata.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set metadata end=eof;
  by variable ;
  file code ;
  retain sep ' ';
  if _n_=1 then put "create table want as select";
  if first.variable then put sep $1. 'case ';
  put '  when (' condition ') then ' category ;
  if last.variable then put '  else . end as ' variable ;
  if eof then put 'from rawdata' / ';' ;
  sep=',' ;
run;
```

And run it.

```
proc sql;
%include code / source2 ;
quit;
```

Example SAS LOG:

```
1639  proc sql;
1640  %include code / source2 ;
NOTE: %INCLUDE (level 1) file CODE is file C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\1\SAS Temporary Files\_TD13724_AMRL20B7F00CGPP_\#LN00654.
1641 +create table want as select
1642 + case
1643 +  when (Var1<20 ) then 1
1644 +  when (40>Var1>=20 ) then 2
1645 +  when (Var1>=40 ) then 3
1646 + else . end as Var1
1647 +,case
1648 +  when (Var2<0.2 ) then 1
1649 +  when (Var2>=0.2 ) then 2
1650 + else . end as Var2
1651 +from rawdata
1652 +;
NOTE: Table WORK.WANT created, with 3 rows and 2 columns.
```

Results:

```
Obs    Var1    Var2

 1       1       2
 2       2       1
 3       3       2
```

If you want to convert it to macro then just replace the hard coded input dataset names and output dataset names with macro variable references.

```
%macro gencat(indata=,outdata=,metadata=metadata);

filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set &metadata end=eof;
  by variable ;
  file code ;
  retain sep ' ';
  if _n_=1 then put "create table &outdata as select";
  if first.variable then put sep $1. 'case ';
  put '  when (' condition ') then ' category ;
  if last.variable then put ' else . end as ' variable ;
  if eof then put "from &indata" / ';' ;
  sep=',' ;
run;

proc sql;
%include code / nosource2 ;
quit;

%mend gencat;
```

So now the same result is gotten by calling with these values:

```
%gencat(indata=rawdata,outdata=want)
```

So the log now looks like this:

```
1783  %gencat(indata=rawdata,outdata=want)
MPRINT(GENCAT):   filename code temp;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           10.35 seconds
      cpu time            0.20 seconds


MPRINT(GENCAT):   data _null_;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   set metadata end=eof;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   by variable ;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   file code ;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   retain sep ' ';
MPRINT(GENCAT):   if _n_=1 then put "create table want as select";
MPRINT(GENCAT):   if first.variable then put sep $1. 'case ';
MPRINT(GENCAT):   put '  when (' condition ') then ' category ;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   if last.variable then put ' else . end as ' variable ;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   if eof then put "from rawdata" / ';' ;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   sep=',' ;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   run;

NOTE: The file CODE is:
      Filename=C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\1\SAS Temporary Files\_TD13724_AMRL20B7F00CGPP_\#LN00659,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=32767,File Size (bytes)=0,
      Last Modified=02Feb2018:12:36:39,
      Create Time=02Feb2018:12:36:39

NOTE: 12 records were written to the file CODE.
      The minimum record length was 1.
      The maximum record length was 28.
NOTE: There were 5 observations read from the data set WORK.METADATA.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds

MPRINT(GENCAT):   proc sql;
MPRINT(GENCAT):   create table want as select case when (Var1<20 ) then 1 when (40>Var1>=20 ) then 2 when (Var1>=40 ) then 3 else .
end as Var1 ,case when (Var2<0.2 ) then 1 when (Var2>=0.2 ) then 2 else . end as Var2 from rawdata ;
NOTE: Table WORK.WANT created, with 3 rows and 2 columns.

MPRINT(GENCAT):   quit;
```

Comment: Im running into this everytime I trye the code that starts with data _null_ ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set DAT.CONDITIONS

Comment: This program is assuming that the rules to generate a specific new category variable are grouped together.  So sort the metadata by the variable VARIABLE. You might want to sort it by some other variable also (for example `by variable line_number`) so that the WHEN() conditions are generated in the order you want.  If the conditions are not mutually exclusive then the order can make a big difference in the category that is assigned. But the step that generates the CASE statement just needs the metadata sorted by VARIABLE.

Comment: I added samples from my datasets, keep in mind that the datasets have about 200 variables and the table with conditions has around 600 of them.

Comment: Your example conditions file looks fine.  Either change the code in this answer to use your variable names, or convert your data to use the names that this code is expecting.  `proc sort data=conditions(rename=(war=condition zmienna=variable nrobs=category)) out=metadata; by variable category; run;`

Comment: Okay this code you provided when I change names of the variables works but then the variables are sorted the opposite that they were before (first becomes last from what i can see). I dont know why if i change the variable names directly in your code (without sorting) then it doesnt work. It looks like this :

Comment: `filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set Dat.conditions end=eof;
  by zmienna ;
  file code ;
  retain sep ' ';
  if _n_=1 then put "create table want as select";
  if first.zmienna then put sep $1. 'case ';
  put '  when (' war ') then ' nrobs ;
  if last.zmienna then put '  else . end as ' zmienna ;
  if eof then put 'from Production_tolist' / ';' ;
  sep=',' ;
run;`

Comment: If you know the records are grouped, but they are not in alphabetical order then you can add the `NOTSORTED` keyword to the `BY` statement in the `data _NULL_` step and it will still set the FIRST. and LAST. variables properly.  If you want the variables defined in the output dataset in a different order than implied by the value of the variable name then add another ordering variable before that in the dataset.  `by varorder zmienna; ... if first.zmienna ...`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro way to accomplish this.  It assumes that the conditions in the table are in the order you want them applied and grouped by variable.  If not, then sort the table appropriately.

First test data:

```
data have;
input Var1 Var2;
datalines;
19   0.2
30   0.1
45   0.2
;

data conditions;
informat variable condition $32.;
input variable $ condition $  category;

datalines;
Var1     Var1<20         1
Var1     40>Var1>=20     2
Var1     Var1>=40        3
Var2     Var2<0.2        1
Var2     Var2>=0.2       2
;
```

Now make a macro.  We will read the table into macro variables and then write a datastep to apply them.  We use IF/THEN/ELSE blocks for each variable.

```
%macro apply_conditions();
%local i j n;
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :n trimmed from conditions;

%do i=1 %to &n;
    %local var&i;
    %local condition&i;
    %local category&i;
%end;

select variable, condition, category
    into :var1       - :var&n,
         :condition1 - :condition&n,
         :category1  - :category&n
    from conditions;
quit;

data want;
set have;

%do i=1 %to &n;
    /*If the variable changes, then don't add the ELSE */
    %if &i>1 %then %do;
        %let j=%eval(&i-1);
        %if &&var&i = &&var&j %then %do;
        else
        %end;
    %end;
    /*apply the condition*/
    if &&condition&i then
        &&var&i = &&category&i;
%end;
run;
%mend;
```

Finally run the macro.  Using `MPRINT` to see the code that is generated.

```
options mprint;
%apply_conditions;
```

Comment: You wrote that /*If the variable changes, then don't add the ELSE */, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I am just looking at the previous value of &&var&i and comparing the two.  If they are the same, then I am in a single IF/THEN/ELSE block.  When it changes, we reset the block by not adding an else.  That way, conditions for VAR1 don't override conditions for VAR2.

Comment: add that example to your test data above.

Comment: I added you to the chat so we could discuss this further